# Facebook live API - Set live video to public

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, privacy, facebook-live-api

So I'm using the javascript SDK. I created the video using:

```
FB.api(
  '/{user-id}/live_videos',
  'POST',
  {"status":"LIVE_NOW","title":"\"Today's Live Video\"","description":"\"This is the live video for today.\""},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

Everything works fine but it sets the video to private and when I go to facebook and try to change it to public, it still can't be accessed. Is there a way to set it to public inside the code above?

Comment: Probably because the App is not Live.

Comment: @WizKid so once I do that, the video will be created public by default?

Comment: There could of course be other reasons